Is there an extra operation when using the negative number shorthand in C#?
In C# one can make a positive int negative using the minus sign - like so:
var positiveInt = 5;
var negativeInt = -positiveInt;

Is there an extra operation taking place under the hood when doing this (i.e. is the CPU actually multiplying the number by -1)?

int is 4 bytes. No matter what you stick into 4 bytes, performance is the same

Why, oh why, would you waste time working on micro-optimizations that wouldn't make any impact at all on any code, even if it did (which it doesn't)? Don't you have more important things to focus on, like writing actual code? Do you have anything from a profiler that indicates a performance area in this area of your code that would make you be looking at it?

"Is a cost incurred when doing this ..." - stop writing fiction books. Write code! The only cost could be is if you use numbers between 5 and 10 and use int, but could use short

@T.S. I am not talking about storage cost. I am asking if there is an extra mathematical operation taking place.

In the general case, if the value of the operand is unknown, then yes, an extra neg instruction (for x86) is emitted to negate the value. However, if the value of the operand is known, as in your example, then the JIT compiler will perform constant propagation and just initialize negativeInt to 0xfffffffb, representing the constant value -5. Disassembly

@MichaelLiu Perfect, post this as an answer and I'll mark it

Isn't int allocates one position for sign? During declaration it has no impact, it just sets that position

@T.S. not likely. It’s twos complement

You can use SharpLab or the Godbolt Compiler Explorer to see what the .NET JIT compiler emits for various pieces of code. In particular, it's instructive to compare the following two methods:
static int M1()
{
    var positiveInt = 5;
    var negativeInt = -positiveInt;
    return negativeInt;
}

static int M2(int positiveInt)
{
    var negativeInt = -positiveInt;
    return negativeInt;
}

For M1, the JIT compiler performs constant propagation and emits code that simply returns 0xfffffffb, representing the constant -5:
mov eax, 0xfffffffb
ret

But for M2, where the positiveInt argument in register ecx is an unknown value, the JIT compiler emits a neg instruction (for x86) that negates the value:
mov eax, ecx
neg eax
ret


Wow, you deserve the points for wasting your time with this (great) answer.

Just one note: the compiler uses the neg instruction when the context of the operation is unchecked. When it's checked, it uses a sub.ovf (subtracting your source value from zero). These are CIL instructions, but the same goes for the x86/x64 instructions.
